# Unit testing of complex objects C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I wrote a short application, but I ran into the problem of writing a unit test Method MaximumRowSum_DefectiveLines. Please tell me how I should act, my class for testing

```
public class OutputtingStrings
{
    public class MaxSumLineResult
    {
        public int MaxSumLineIndex { get; set; }
        public List<string> DefectiveLines { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Line number with maximum sum of elements: { MaxSumLineIndex + 1}"; /* + "\n" +
                 $"Defective lines:{string.Join("\n", DefectiveLines)}";*/
        }
    }

    public static bool IsValidateFileExist(string filePath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public MaxSumLineResult MaximumRowSum_DefectiveLines(string[] fileData)
    {
        List<string> defectiveLines = new List<string>();
        int lineNumber = 0;
        var indexOfLines = new Dictionary<int, double>();
        foreach (var line in fileData)
        {
            NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Number;
            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");

            var stringElements = line.Split(",",  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (stringElements.Any(n => double.TryParse(n, style, culture, out var number)))
            {
                indexOfLines.Add(lineNumber, stringElements.Sum(n =>
                {
                    return double.Parse(n, style, culture);
                }));
            }
             else  
            {
                 defectiveLines.Add(line);
            }

            lineNumber++;

        }
        var maxSumLineIndex = indexOfLines.FirstOrDefault(x =>
           x.Value == indexOfLines.Values.Max()).Key;

        var resultLines = new MaxSumLineResult
        {
            MaxSumLineIndex = maxSumLineIndex,
            DefectiveLines = defectiveLines
        };

        return resultLines;
    }
}
```

My unit testing class:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTestOutputtingStrings
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_FindingMaximumRowSum_TheFileIsValidAndReadable()
    {
        /* Arrange*/
        var maxsumlineresult = new MaxSumLineResult();
        var sut = new OutputtingStrings();

        /* Act*/

        /* Assert*/
    }
}
```

I have read the book "The Art of Unit Testing. With Examples in C#". I understand the principles, but I do not know how to work with complex classes. Thank you guys in advance, I will be glad to every answer or link to a source with materials on unit testing.

Comment: Prepare some test string array, call `MaximumRowSum_DefectiveLines` and check the return value.

Comment: Construct an example you can easily solve in your head. Then check if the return value of your method matches the expected output if you feed your method with that example string array.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For sure in the method, there is too much responsibility.
I think that the good idea to start is to divide the method into more than one smaller methods. After that unit testing of that method would be simpler to be done.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, the principle of single responsibility must be respected.

Comment: This seems more like a suggestion than an answer. Perhaps it should be in the comments rather than posted as an answer?